# How do you render custom variables into HTML with webpack-dev-middleware?

Tags: javascript, express, webpack, webpack-dev-middleware

I use Webpack to compile my JS which is then loaded via `bundle.js` via a template string sent via express.

The only problem is, I can't find information on how to render custom html while also using `webpack-dev-middleware` to watch and compile `bundle.js`.

My HTML is being sent with the following code:

```
app.use('*', (req, res) => {
    res.send(`
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html lang="en">
        <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8" />
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
          <title>Title</title>
        </head>
        <body>
          <noscript>
            You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
          </noscript>

          <div id="main"></div>

          <script type="text/javascript">window.__userData=${JSON.stringify(req.user)}</script>
          <script src="/bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        </body>
        </html>`);
});
```

So, I have no idea how I can keep/use this while using `webpack-dev-middleware` for the `bundle.js`, since what I tried to do was just add `app.use` as per `webpack-dev-middleware` before the above snippet, though it did not work, failing with the error of bundle.js being of the wrong mime type `text/html`, thus not executable.

---

**EDIT**

The server-side rendering option for `webpack-dev-middleware` is experimental and not what I'm looking for, I don't need raw `bundle.js` to send with html.

Comment: if all you need is to watch and compile bundle.js why dont you simply write a gulp task for that purpose or just use nodemon/forever?

Comment: @Manticore I've setup webpack todo all my compiling, I don't feel changing to gulp is a wise solution, I'll need to write brand new compile script for gulp. Webpack is also crazy fast with its in-memory dev middleware/server.

Comment: do your scripts change on runtime? i mean do they really have to be recompiled by the webapplication?

Comment: @Manticore I see what you mean, It's for development though, so only runs when node env is set to development. I require it to be compiled as it's React, so code base is spread over many files. I've come up with a temporary solution that'll appease me for the time being, I'm going to use Webpacks node api to watch and compile, it has a callback so I can tell browser to refresh, websocket, polling or something.

Comment: @sparcut is your solution available somewhere (i.e. github) ?